# Indexing all elements of permutations $S_n$

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, permutation

I have this Table that gives all elements of $S_n$,  I would like to know how to improve efficiency.

```
Table[i -> Part[Permutations[Table[n, {n, k}]], j, i], {j, k!}, {i, k}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Already at `k==7`, this version is 85 times faster:

```
With[{k = 7}, Thread[Range[k] -> #] & /@ Permutations[Range[k]]]
```

[image]

To make sure:

```
With[{k = 5}, Table[i -> Part[Permutations[Table[n, {n, k}]], j, i], {j, k!}, {i, k}]]
  === 
 With[{k = 5}, Thread[Range[k] -> #] & /@ Permutations[Range[k]]]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best I found so far is the following `f3` (indeed very similar to the one of garej)

```
f1[k_] := Thread[Range[k] -> #] & /@ Permutations[Range[k]]
f2[k_] := With[{r = Range@k}, Thread[r -> #] & /@ Permutations@r]
f3[k_] := With[{r = Range@k}, 
  Transpose@MapThread[Thread@*Rule, {r, Transpose@Permutations@r}]]
f4[k_] := Transpose[Thread[# -> Permutations[Range[k]][[All, #]]] & /@ Range[k]];
```

Comparison:

```
data = Table[First@RepeatedTiming@f[k], {f, {f1, f2, f3, f4}}, {k, 7}]
ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"march", 2, 3, "garej"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

> {{9.5*10^-6, 0.000014, 0.000034, 0.00012, 0.00066, 0.0042, 
>     0.033}, {9.3*10^-6, 0.0000126, 0.00002718, 0.00010, 0.00054, 0.0035,
>      0.028}, {0.000013, 0.000017, 0.000026, 0.0000614, 0.00030, 0.0022, 
>     0.018}, {0.0000112, 0.0000188, 0.0000316, 0.000080, 0.00033, 0.0023,
>      0.02}}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: why didn't you add my version to comparison?

Comment: @garej sorry, I started improving the one of march; now added

Comment: no problem - I've also made a shorter one with `Inner`

Answer (score 2):

My favourite one is:

```
foo[k_]:= Inner[Rule, Range[k], Transpose @ Permutations[Range[k]], List]
```

This is also a fast option conceptually close to OP approach:

```
Transpose[Thread[# -> Permutations[Range[k]][[All, #]]] & /@ Range[k]];
```

**Timing** with Unlikely's comparison method for `k = {7,8,9}` on (i5, Win10, V10.30) `Inner` is a bit faster.
:

[image]

**Edit** Just for diversity:

```
MapIndexed[Last[#2] -> #1 &, Permutations[Range[5]], {2}]
```